# SQL syntax should work but not working What could be the issue?

Tags: mysql, sql

`GRANT ALL ON *.* TO demoemployee@'1.5.6.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password'`

**Error:**   *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password'' at line 1*

I don't see any issue with the syntax above but still, it's not working and adding an extra `'` on the end of my query.

I've tried this on my MySQL server 8.xx and on online tools like this: https://en.rakko.tools/tools/36/

I've also tried few other queries but couldn't solve.

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password'`

How Should I resolve this?

Comment: Create the user first if it is not created yet with: `create user  'demoemployee'@'1.5.6.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password';` and then grant the permission: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES  ON *.* TO 'demoemployee'@'1.5.6.4'`

Comment: @ErgestBasha Doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the [documentation of `GRANT` in MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) to [those of 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) reveals that authentication characteristics are no longer supported. The 5.7 version also explicitly warns that they *already* are deprecated in 5.7 and are subject to removal in future versions:

> **Note**
>
> Use of `GRANT` to define account authentication characteristics is
> deprecated in MySQL 5.7. Instead, establish or change authentication
> characteristics using `CREATE USER` or `ALTER USER`. Expect this
> `GRANT` capability to be removed in a future MySQL release.

So simply remove `IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password'`.

Comment: Doesn't work either. 

`you are not allowed to create a user with grant`